# Why are collections classes in .NET not generic?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

After all the fuss about non-generic classes being obsolete (well almost) why are .NET collection classes still non-generic? For instance, [Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) doesn't implement `IList<T>` but only `IList`, or [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formcollection.aspx) implements only upto `ICollection` and not `ICollection<T>`. Everytime I have to do some cool operation available on `IEnumerable<T>` or avail `Linq` niceties, I have to invariably convert the collection classes to its equivalent generic type like this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Control>();
```

Its weird to have to specify `Control` in an operation like this on `ControlCollection` when the only thing it can hold is again a Control.

Is it to maintain backward compatibility, considering these collections existed back in .Net 1.1 days? Even if it is, why cant these collections (there are many many more) further implement generic interfaces along with the existing ones which I believe wouldnt break backward compatibility. I am unsure if I am missing something key to generics, may be I am not thorough with the idea..

**Edit:** Though I asked this when I had only WinForms in mind, I find this applies to newer technologies like WPF too. As @Dennis points out WPF too has non-generic collections. For instance [WindowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowcollection.aspx) or the [ItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx). WPF was released along .NET 3, but generics was introduced in .NET 2 :-o

### Update to this:

There is a ticket for this now: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/2644 (.NET Core of course).

Comment: Your title is about '.NET Collections', your examples about WinForms. Please be specific.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok I didn't know that. Does that mean newer technologies like WPF has equivalent Collection classes generic?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Collections in SMO, derived from `SmoCollectionBase`, collections in WPF (e.g., `ResourceDictionary`) are non-generic too... These are relatively new technologies, invented after generics in .NET. Working with them is a pain. And this is just two examples, which was quickly remembered.

Comment: In WPF, some collections are generic (ObservableCollection<>) but only where appropriate.  Databinding requires flexibility.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: `ObservableCollection<T>` isn't a part of WPF anyway! Although, this type of collections if often used in MVVM-applications.

Comment: If WPF was designed today, it would use a lot of `dynamic`.

Comment: Note that if you know that all elements are in fact instances of `Control` (or of a derived type), it's more efficient to use `.Cast<Control>()` rather than `.OfType<Control>()`.  OfType means "some of these things might not be controls; check them and return only the ones that are" while Cast means "all of these things are controls; cast them all to that type."

Comment: @phoog though performance almost never matters, I consistently (in my earlier and current tests) find that `OfType` performs marginally better than `Cast`. Just wondering why. So I always used `OfType`, though `Cast` is better as far as naming goes.

Comment: @nawfal interesting, I will look into that.

Comment: @downvoter? some comments please..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it to maintain backward compatibility, considering these collections existed back in .Net 1.1 days?

Yes, but mostly because WinForms has been 'Feature Complete' since 2005 or even earlier.

Feature Complete means it's on life-support, just short of do-not-resuscitate.

#### Additonal, re the Edit:

The WindowsCollection is already 'specialized', it contains classes derived from Window. Inheritance is the right model here, generics are not called for.

And the ItemCollection is intentionally non-generic as well. It is a deliberate feature that it can contain all types, even different types at the same time. Again, generics is not necessary and not desirable.

Comment: I didn't know WinForms was declared not to extend its existing capabilities. Can you tell me what other platforms are considered to be so?

Comment: I don't have a list. Non-generic collections and Datasets come to mind.

Comment: Henk, no I meant, what other platforms are under `do-not-resusciate` plan?If WinForms is one, what are the other ones, say like wpf, silverlight etc?

Comment: @nawfal I think Silverlight is under that category, or at least very close.

Comment: WPF and Silverlight are in the same category as WinForms, there is no active UI framework for Desktop applications at the moment, only Xaml for WinRt

Comment: I don't know of any official statements about other platforms. Other than that WPF and SL are 'less actively developed'. But I wouldn't toss them in with WinForms just yet.

Comment: Generics was introduced in .NET 2 which was around 2005. Even if WinForms got completed by 2005, what about WPF that came along .NET 3?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't get the argument in your edit. I see little downsides to at least implementing `IEnumerable<Window>` etc. and possibly even `IList<Window>`. The OP isn't asking to make those classes generic, but to implement the generic collection interfaces.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - you're right about the interfaces, they could even be added w/o breaking anything. But WPF was started (not released) before generics. I suppose there never was a direct need to upgrade the collections before LINQ, and by then the dev effort in WPF was already reduced.

Comment: For an update: WinForms is far from dead. Still getting cool little updates from even [next gen .NET releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.140%29.aspx#v46). It's dying, yes, but not dead yet :)